# Entity-Framework SQL command time-out

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, timeout, sqlcommand

I'm using `Entity Framework 4.0` as part of my `DAL` for a web project. I have a busy table which is updated frequently. At the time of update, I do the job as a `Transaction`. Everything is OK most of the time but sometimes I get the following error:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred
>   while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
>   details.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.Execute(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand.ExecuteScalar[T_Result](Func`2
>   resultSelector)
>
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String
>   functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>
>   at  Downloading.Entities.DownloadingEntities.DoSomethingEx(Nullable`1 id,
>   ...)
>     in ...\DAL\DownloadingEntities.Designer.cs:line 2035
>   at Downloading.DAL.Repository.DoSomething(Int64 Id, ...)
>     in ...\DAL\Repository.cs:line 982

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Show us what you're doing - what code fragment is causing this error? What are you trying to do in that code??

Comment: @marc_s: I call `DoSomething` on `EF` which is mapped on a `Stored Procedure`. This `SP` updates the busy table I mentioned. There are ~20,000 records on this table and update frequency is ~200-500 per second. I use transaction and try/catch in my `SP`.

Answer (score -2):

Try increasing "connection timeout" in you SQL server connection string.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)

Comment: This is a `Command Time-Out` which is different from `Connection Time-Out`

Comment: That makes sense, but actually I didn't try it yet. U want to know if this is a common situation with `EF` or something is wrong with my design.